# How to implement collection view context menus AND cell reordering

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm making a photo gallery app. I had successfully implemented cell reordering with a long press gesture recognizer. It then occurred to me to implement context menus for e.g. deleting a photo, so I added `contextMenuConfigurationForItemsAt`. This worked and gave me context menus, but now my gesture recognizer doesn't work. Has anyone successfully done both?

Here's my reordering code (doesn't include the moveItemAt logic but that doesn't seem relevant here as it can't get far enough to call that). The long press gesture is attached to the collectionView in viewDidLoad.

```
 var longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!
 var isEnded: Bool = true
 var currentCell: UICollectionViewCell? = nil


@objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    
    switch(gesture.state) {
    case .began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        isEnded = false
        //store selected cell in currentCell variable
        currentCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
        collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
    case .changed:
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
    case .ended:
        isEnded = true
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        }) { (result) in
            self.currentCell = nil
        }
    default:
        isEnded = true
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```